# Taylor Polynomial And Reminder In Lagrange Form

Tags: calculus

> What is the error of Taylor polynomial of $\sin(x)$ of order 4 around $x_0=0$ at the point $-1$?

So the Taylor polynomial is $x-\frac{x^3}{3!}$ and the remainder in  Lagrange form is $$\frac{\cos(c)}{5!}\cdot x^5$$

So $-1\leq c\leq 1$ and therefore it is $\frac{\cos(c)}{5!}\cdot x^5\leq \frac{1}{120}$ so the error can be at most $+/-\frac{1}{120}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it just ask you to find the error, it should be
$$|\sin{(-1)}-((-1)-\frac{(-1)^3}{3!})|$$

If it asks you to find the error bound
$$\left|\frac{\cos{c}}{5!}(-1)^5\right|\leq \frac{1}{120}$$
since $-1\leq c\leq 0$.

**Edit**: As pointed out by @Bernard, the error is defined by 
$$f-T_n$$
In this case
$$\sin{(-1)}-((-1)-\frac{(-1)^3}{3!})$$

Comment: Moreover, by Leibniz criterion, we know the error is $<0$.

Comment: @Bernard as it is bounded by the next element of the series? could it be positive?

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you for pointing that out. Just did some research. The "error" in the context of taylor expansion is defined as $f_n-T_n$. As you pointed out, in this example, it should be negative. Just to make a note, in some other context of numerical analysis, error is defined as absolute value of the difference of the true value and the approximation.

Comment: It has the same sign as the next element. Be careful however: here $x<0$.

Comment: @KittyL what does $T_n$ donate to?

Comment: @gbox: $T_n$ stands for the Taylor polynomial for $f$ of $n$-th order.

Comment: @KittyL so according to Leibniz the error should be $\frac{\cos(-1)}{5!}$?
http://i.imgur.com/7e5dd6Q.png

Comment: @gbox: That is the error bound, with $-1$ replaced by $c$. See my second statement in my answer. This is usually useful when you don't specify the order of the Taylor expansion. This problem is asking you the error, with order $4$, which can be explicitly found by the last formula in the answer.